# Place of birth listed on immigration docs but where in Russia is Kosnitza/Kosnitze?

Tags: naming-convention, russia, jewish, place-names, historical-gazetteer

My Jewish family who came to Canada in 1924, from Bucharest on the SS Madonna, list their nationality as Russian,  4 family members put their place of birth as Kosnitza, and Kosnitze.

Does anyone know where this place is?

I know spellings and pronunciations differ but I am really stuck.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE!  While you are waiting for an answer, take a look at some of our other questions about [finding towns in Russia](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/search?q=finding+town+Russia) to see if the resources there can help you.  If you'd like to edit your message to include a snippet from the passenger list showing the town name, please do. But please don't include the names of anyone living, or recently deceased unless they were born over 100 years ago.

Answer (score 4):

It was likely Velikaya Kosnitsa. It had sizeable Jewish population in the beginning of XX century:
http://www.jewishgen.org/ukraine/GEO_town.asp?id=313
Here is some additional info about it (Russian language only):http://jukraine.org/vinnickaya-oblast/velikaya_kosnica/

Answer (score 1):

Or perhaps...Kozienice, in Poland
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kozienice - although I cannot find a reference in its wikipedia page about it being under russian rule for sometime, it might have happened. Other than that, Kozienice once had a large and traditional jewish community. I have ancestors from there.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  Thankyou for taking the time to look at an older question like this.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome message :-). I was searching posts tagged "jewish", that's the only field I can help.

Comment: Yes, thats possible too.  Kozienice was a part of Russian Empire indeed, you can look for a map here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congress_Poland, it's roughly in the middle between Lublin and Warsaw.